# Printer can't read my G-code file

Tags: creality-ender-5, sd

I've been trying to print a part through an SD card, but my printer doesn't show my G-code file.

I thought the SD card was not working but then I tried printing an old file I had and it's working just fine.

So I am wondering what can be wrong?

I also tried to change the name of the file to redo the converting from STL to G-code and nothing seems to work...

Comment: Can you share the file for us to look into? These are plain text files, so can you share through the PasteBin website?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer I finally was able to solve the problem. seems like the name of the file was too long that's why it was not appearing on the printer.

Comment: Great you solved the problem! Please add your solution as an answer and accept the answer after 48 hours! Happy printing!